# human-readable mongoose errors

Tags: mongoose

Is there a best practice for cleaning up the errors returned by mongoose? For example, on a save I got the following duplicate key error:

`MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error index: dev.users.$username_1  dup key: { : "dweldon" }`

I'd like to return something useful to the user but right now I'm parsing error strings in my controllers, which smells like a piping hot cup of wrong.

Comment: There is now a plugin for this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-beautiful-unique-validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't parse the string, check the numeric `code` property of the `MongoError` object and present sensible feedback to the user based on the indicated type of error.  In your example the code value is `11000`.

Comment: That works if I want to give the user a generic message like "a value you entered is already in the database", as opposed to something specific like "this username is already taken".

Comment: @DavidWeldon The point is to use the `code` value to make the determination.  It's up to the specifics of your app how to communicate the specific impact to the user.

Comment: Indeed. It would be nice if I could perform those checks in the model itself, but I'm not sure how to do that without putting a wrapper function around `save`.

Comment: @DavidWeldon You could do that, but having user-facing error message strings down in the database model doesn't feel right to me.  Should be higher up in the stack.